# No more webhook callbacks?

Tags: square-connect

as of yesterday (7/7/16) at some point in the early morning my live Square Connect application, Wifitimer, stopped receiving any webhook callbacks from Square Connect.  Is there a problem on the Square side? I have 9 active locations with active tokens servicing hundreds of end users each day.

Why are the webhooks suddenly not calling back?  I'm seeing nothing hit my application.

Having to rewrite to pull and not rely on Square Connect to push.

Answer (score 2):

Having the same problem with both OAuth & personal access token applications.  Test webhooks we send from the app in connect.squareup.com work fine so we think it has something to do in Square's side.  We update a bunch of locations and we haven't received any webhook info since 1:50 pm Central on 7/6.  We've had an open ticket w/ Square Support since shortly after that time, have called & talked to them multiple times but no explanation or response yet.  Didn't know if it was just us or if others were affected.

We're pulling data down hourly which seems to be working fine.  Recommend using a regular script which searches for missing data even when webhooks working.  That is what is keeping us updated now.

Answer (score 1):

We had an internal issue that caused notifications to get backed up for roughly a couple of days. This has been resolved and you should be receiving callbacks now.

Comment: Could you guys please add a status for your systems, better yet, some notifications for developers that are writing for your API?  Having a key element of a major API go down for a couple days matters. If you want to attract developers please add some transparency here.  This is the second major outage you've had in 12 months - my clients notice, and they were not happy.  My software now has code to work around and expect Square Connect webhook outages, which I wish wasn't needed.